# How do you read post variables in python-eve?

Tags: python, rest, eve

How do we read post variables in python-eve ?

If I do

```
curl -d [ {"firstname" : "Barack", "lastname":"Obama"} ] <url>
```

how would I read post variables[firstname and lastname] inside the program ?

Thanks !

Comment: do you want a prefix, or a filter using the endpoints ?

Comment: I want to get list of all people in data when I say 

curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/people/presidents/america

I do not want to filter or prefix

Comment: but that would be different from just `/people/` ?

Comment: I am experimenting with my application. That is what mu URL is and I want to keep it like that. Later I want to a post operation with 
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:5000/people/presidents/England/POST/[--array of England prime ministers]. Customizing would be really helpful for my application

Answer (score 1):

I post this with the caveat that you are probably not defining and requesting your resources correctly.

This makes your freshly posted values available in a list named 'items'

```
from eve import Eve

def read_insert(resource, items):
  print 'resource: "%s"' % resource
  print 'items: "%s"' % items
  pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = Eve()
  app.on_insert += read_insert

  app.run()
```